# Cannot process the message because the content type 'application / xml' was not the expected type 'application / soap + xml; charset = utf-8 '

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

> The remote server returned an error: (415) Cannot process the message because the content type 'application / xml' was not the expected type 'application / soap + xml; charset = utf-8 '

I just try to launch my self host. I have 2 endpoints with Basic Authentication. So I had to use wsHttpBinding for that. CreateUser endpoint should use XML format and RemoveUser endpoint - json format.

I attached my selfhost app.config, client main function and contract.

#### server app.config

```
<services>
  <service name="Web.Service.Core.Services.UserContract"
           behaviorConfiguration="AuthBehavior" >
    <endpoint address="CreateUser"
              binding="wsHttpBinding"
              bindingNamespace="http://localhost/Auth/"
              contract="Web.Service.Library.Contracts.IUserContract" />
    <endpoint address="RemoveUser"
              binding="wsHttpBinding"
              contract="Web.Service.Library.Contracts.IUserContract" />
```

#### IUserContract.cs

```
[ServiceContract(Namespace = "http://localhost/Auth/", ProtectionLevel = ProtectionLevel.None)]
[XmlSerializerFormat]
public interface IUserContract
{
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "POST",
        UriTemplate = "Auth/CreateUser",
        RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml,
        ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml,
        BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped)]
    Response CreateUser(Stream xml);

    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "POST",
        UriTemplate = "Auth/RemoveUser",
        RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
        ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
        BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped)]
    Response RemoveUser(Stream stream);
```

#### client main()

```
var webRequest = (HttpWebRequest) WebRequest.Create(CreateUserUrl);
webRequest.Method = "POST";
webRequest.ContentType = "application/xml";
webRequest.ContentLength = data.Length;
var rqStream = webRequest.GetRequestStream();
rqStream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
rqStream.Close();
var webResponse = webRequest.GetResponse();
var rsStream = webResponse.GetResponseStream();
var responseXml = new StreamReader(rsStream);
var s = responseXml.ReadToEnd();
```

Comment: Do as the error says, send the proper content-type header. Or better, generate a WCF client.

Comment: I can not to generate a client. VS does not see my contracts :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When we use wshttpbinding to create WCF service, the service based on the web service speficification, and use Simple Object Access Protocol to communicate. We could check the communication details by using fiddler.
[image]
The content-type is Application/soap+xml instead of the Application/xml, and the request body format based on SOAP envelop.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOAP
This kind of web service is called SOAP web service. Ordinarily, we call the service by using the client proxy class.

```
   ServiceReference1.ServiceClient client = new ServiceClient();
            try
            {
                var result = client.GetData();
                Console.WriteLine(result);
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {

                throw;
            }
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/accessing-services-using-a-wcf-client
The way you call a service usually applies to Restful-style service.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/best-practices/api-design
Instantiate the HttpClient class and custom the request body. Under this circumstance, we should use WebHttpBinding in WCF to create the service. Please refer to my reply.
[How to fix "ERR_ABORTED 400 (Bad Request)" error with Jquery call to C# WCF service?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56873239/how-to-fix-err-aborted-400-bad-request-error-with-jquery-call-to-c-sharp-wcf/56879896#56879896)
Feel free to let me know if there is anything I can help with.

**Updated.**

```
class Program
{
    /// <summary>
    /// https webhttpbinding.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="args"></param>
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Uri uri = new Uri("https://localhost:4386");
        WebHttpBinding binding = new WebHttpBinding();
        binding.Security.Mode = WebHttpSecurityMode.Transport;
        binding.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = HttpClientCredentialType.Basic;


        using (WebServiceHost sh = new WebServiceHost(typeof(TestService), uri))
        {
            sh.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(ITestService), binding, "");
            ServiceMetadataBehavior smb;
            smb = sh.Description.Behaviors.Find<ServiceMetadataBehavior>();
            if (smb == null)
            {
                smb = new ServiceMetadataBehavior()
                {
                    //HttpsGetEnabled = true
                };
                sh.Description.Behaviors.Add(smb);

            }
            Binding mexbinding = MetadataExchangeBindings.CreateMexHttpsBinding();
            sh.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IMetadataExchange), mexbinding, "mex");


            sh.Opened += delegate
            {
                Console.WriteLine("service is ready");
            };
            sh.Closed += delegate
            {
                Console.WriteLine("service is closed");
            };
            sh.Open();

            Console.ReadLine();

            sh.Close();
        }
    }
}
[ServiceContract]
public interface ITestService
{
    [OperationContract]
    [WebGet(ResponseFormat =WebMessageFormat.Json)]
    string GetResult();
}

[ServiceBehavior]
public class TestService : ITestService
{
    public string GetResult()
    {
        return $"Hello, busy World. {DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString()}";
    }
}
```

Bind a certificate to the port(Powershell command).

```
    netsh http add sslcert ipport=0.0.0.0:4386 certhash=cbc81f77ed01a9784a12483030ccd497f01be71c App
id='{61466809-CD17-4E31-B87B-E89B003FABFA}'
```

Result.
[image]

Comment: Thank you for the response. But i have additional question: How can i use basic auth with webHttpBinding ?

Comment: We need to set up the client credential type of the webhttpbinding to basic, if necessary, l will post an example.

Comment: I added configuration for this. `<endpoint address="CreateUser"
                  binding="webHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="WebHttpBinding"
                  contract="Web.Service.Library.Contracts.IUserContract" />` and `<webHttpBinding>
        <binding name="WebHttpBinding">
          <security mode="Transport">
            <transport clientCredentialType="Basic" />
          </security>
        </binding>
      </webHttpBinding>`

Comment: No problem, we also need to bind a certificate to the https address port if the transport security mode is specified.

Comment: Oh. So, for using xml/json i need to use webHttpBinding. Then i need to use Basic Authentication. For that i need use https instead http.If I understand correctly please tell me, how can i add https without using iis and asp ? Is there a better and easiest solution?

Comment: It needed for localhost solution only.

Comment: We could use Console application to host the service, and use Netsh http command to bind a certificate to a specifical port. 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/http/add-sslcert
netsh http add sslcert ipport=0.0.0.0:8000 certhash=0000000000003ed9cd0c315bbb6dc1c08da5e6 appid={00112233-4455-6677-8899-AABBCCDDEEFF}

Comment: Thank you! I did it but now i have an error on the client side: "The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a receive". I am trying to fix it.

Comment: It may be the client's distrust of the server certificate that caused the problem. Please note that my browser address bar has a sign of security lock, which means that the client trusts the server certificate. We need to install the certificate in the client LocalCA.

Comment: I imported my cert, than i added this code to client:
`                webRequest.ClientCertificates.Add(new X509Certificate(File.ReadAllBytes(@"C:\App\crt.pfx"), "password"));
` But now i have the same error :(

Comment: Have you solved the problem? We needn’t import the certificate on the client-side.  We need to do is installing the certificate on the client-side CA so that the server certificate is trusted by the client-side. Alternatively, we add the below code before sending an HTTP request.

Comment: Still not solved. My client and service are on localhost machine both. I added the certificate to CA.https://cdn1.imggmi.com/uploads/2019/8/19/917dbe508229ad3b63fe8d6f6283bbe8-full.png

Comment: Since the topic we are currently discussing has deviated too much from the topic of the post, I suggest that you re-post a new post to discuss how to call the service on the client-side.