# WCF Call the service on the client-side

Tags: c#, .net, http, wcf, https

I have a little wcf test application with rest-api endpoints. When i added basic auth to them i got error message that i must to use https instead http. Can i use basic auth without https on localhost server-client communication ?

Contract:

```
[WebInvoke(Method = "POST",
        UriTemplate = "Auth/Create",
        RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml,
        ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml,
        BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped)]
    Response Create(Stream stream);
```

app.config

```
<behavior name="AuthBehavior">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
    </behavior>
<services>
  <service name="Web.Service.Core.Services.AuthContract"
           behaviorConfiguration="AuthBehavior" >
    <endpoint address="Create"
              binding="webHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="WebHttpBindingConfig"
              contract="Web.Service.Library.Contracts.IAuthContract" />

    <endpoint address="mex"
              binding="mexHttpsBinding"
              contract="IMetadataExchange" />
    <host>
      <baseAddresses>
        <add baseAddress="http://localhost/Auth/" />
      </baseAddresses>
    </host>
  </service>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Buddy, if the last reply help you, please mark it as useful.
[Cannot process the message because the content type 'application / xml' was not the expected type 'application / soap + xml; charset = utf-8 '](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57499619/cannot-process-the-message-because-the-content-type-application-xml-was-not/57504501?noredirect=1#comment101571599_57504501)
The error message might be caused by the MEX endpoint configuration, Restful service doesn’t need to have metadata endpoint,we could directly remove it.

```
<endpoint address="mex"
          binding="mexHttpsBinding"
          contract="IMetadataExchange" />
```

Ordinarily, WCF created by WebHttpBinding with Basic authentication could be achieved over HTTP protocol, such as the below example. I use Console application to host the service.
**Server-side.**

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            using (ServiceHost sh=new ServiceHost(typeof(MyService)))
            {
                sh.Open();
                Console.WriteLine("Service is ready....");

                Console.ReadLine();
                sh.Close();
            }
        }

    }

    [ServiceContract]
    interface IService
    {
        [OperationContract]
        [WebGet]
        string GetData();
    }
    public class MyService : IService
    {
        public string GetData()
        {
            return DateTime.Now.ToString();
        }
}
```

**Server-side Configuration.**

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name="Server1.MyService">
        <endpoint address="" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="Server1.IService" bindingConfiguration="mybinding"></endpoint>
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="http://localhost:5577"/>
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
      </service>
    </services>
    <bindings>
      <webHttpBinding>
        <binding name="mybinding">
          <security mode="TransportCredentialOnly">
            <transport clientCredentialType="Basic"></transport>
          </security>
        </binding>
      </webHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <webHttp />
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

Sample call.
[image]
Feel free to contact me if there is anything I can help with.

Comment: Hi again :) Mex endpoint was removed. Now i have this error:|
System.InvalidOperationException: The response message must be protected. This is required by an operation of the contract ('IAuthContract', 'http://tempuri.org/'). The protection must be provided by the binding ('WebHttpBinding', 'http://tempuri.org/').

Comment: What is your webhttpbinding security mode since you custom your binding configuration by using bindingconfiguration property?

Comment: `<bindings>
      <webHttpBinding>
        <binding name="WebHttpBindingConfig">
          <security mode="TransportCredentialOnly">
            <transport clientCredentialType="Basic" />
          </security>
        </binding>
      </webHttpBinding>
    </bindings>`

Comment: I didn't run into this error. As shown in the above example, I could host the service properly over the HTTP protocol. Does this error occur on the server-side of the hosting service

Comment: I got this error on localhost server side. My server side is like your example. Could you help me with it ?)

Comment: Please show your completed project, I will try to reproduce the issue as much as possible.

Comment: Friend, it is determined by your faulty contract, which requires that the operation should be encrypted and signed, namely that we should provide a certificate to protect the communication between the server and the client.  In order to solve this issue, we could directly change to ProtectionLevel.None. Alternatively, it is recommended that we should bind a certificate to encrypt and sign the communication by using the transport security mode.

Comment: In the IAuthContract interface definition.  [FaultContractAttribute(
            typeof(WcfFault),
            Action = "http://www.contoso.com/GreetingFault",
            ProtectionLevel = ProtectionLevel.EncryptAndSign
        )]

Comment: Oh realy. Thank you man. Is this application works for you ?
Now i have error: The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found.
Info from server logs: Listen at 'http://localhost/Auth/CreateUser'.
The incoming HTTP request's URI 'http://localhost/Auth/CreateUser' does not match any service operation.

Comment: In postman i have the same error "Endpoint not found.". But if i changed my account password to incorrect password, i had 403 error. I think my client configuration is fine.

Comment: Since we used the UriTemplate property and relative endpoint address.
<endpoint address="CreateUser"
                  binding="webHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="WebHttpBindingConfig"
                  contract="xBet.Web.Service.Library.Contracts.IAuthContract"/>
UriTemplate = "Auth/CreateUser”
The method should be routed by base address and these properties.
http://localhost:9000/auth/createuser/auth/createuser