# Communication between JavaScript and WCF Service Library (WCF Test Client)

Tags: javascript, c#, wcf, soap, wcf-library

there is a web service (WCF Service Library) when I debug the web service project (in Visual Studio) "Test Client WCF" is launched (so I guess its hosted via the Test Client). I have a web service method called "Test" which returns string. When I "call" that method with the Test Client WCF - it works.

When I want to use browser as a client. I go to http://localhost:9001/Name/WebService/WebAPI and I see the web service (xml with some info about methods). **And now I want to use JavaScript to call that Test method.**

I created a client similar to this https://stackoverflow.com/a/11404133 and I replace the `sr` variable (SOAP request) with a request, which is in XML part of the Test method in the "Test Client WCF" and for url I chose http://localhost:9001/Name/WebService/WebAPI . I tried that JavaScript client, but I got some client error -

> `content-type 'text-xml'` is invalid, server wanted
>   `'application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8'`

(unfortunately right now I can't get to the web service, so I don’t know a number of the error and exact message, but there was no other information, beside the content-type). So I changed the request header to `'application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8'`, but then I got error – that tells me:

> The message cannot be processed at the receiver, due to an
>   AddressFilter mismatch at the EndpointDispatcher. Check that the
>   sender and receiver's EndpointAddresses agree

(Or something like that - I had to translated it to english)

I also tried the "JavaScript client" with an existing service, that I found on the internet and with `text/xml` content-type. And it works fine.

Please do you have any advice - how to call the Test method with JavaScript?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The service invocated in Javascript is called Restful style service. WCF is able to create a Restful style service too. But we need to set up some kinds of additional configuration. The service is hosting in IIS express when we test the service in Visual Studio.  It uses the default binding configuration to host the service(BasicHttpBinding), called SOAP web service. The universal way to invocate the service is taking advantage of using service proxy class, that is what the WCFTestClient do.
If we want to invocate the service by using JavaScript, here is a simple demo, wish it is useful to you. Please be aware that the project template is WCF Service Application instead of Service Library project.
 [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56873239/how-to-fix-err-aborted-400-bad-request-error-with-jquery-call-to-c-sharp-wcf/56879896#56879896](http://%20https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56873239/how-to-fix-err-aborted-400-bad-request-error-with-jquery-call-to-c-sharp-wcf/56879896#56879896)
Feel free to let me know if there is something I can help with.