# Change WCF service to accept content-type "application/xml;charset=utf-8"

Tags: c#, wcf

I created WCF service that's going to be consumed by a third-party that needs to accept content-type application/xml;charset=utf-8 and SOAP 1.1 envelope namespace.  The service is currently accepting text/xml;charset=utf-8.  Having the client change the content-type is not an option.

I haven't made any changes to the web.config file, except setting the basicHttpBinding maxReceivedMessageSize.

```
  <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="http" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647"/>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
```

Answer (score 0):

This issue typically due to the service type. Traditional SOAP web service based on the web service specification, SOAP envelope is the communication carrier and **content-type** is **“application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8”** or **“text/xml;charset=utf-8”**(for compatible with XML web service).
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOAP
The specifical HTTP header is commonplace in the Restful style service. WCF could create a restful style service too.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/wcf-web-http-programming-model
Example.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/how-to-create-a-basic-wcf-web-http-service
Here is an example I ever wrote.
[How to fix "ERR_ABORTED 400 (Bad Request)" error with Jquery call to C# WCF service?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56873239/how-to-fix-err-aborted-400-bad-request-error-with-jquery-call-to-c-sharp-wcf/56879896#56879896)
Feel free to let me know if there is anything I can help with.

Comment: I got the service working with REST and accepting "application/xml; charset=utf-8", but now I'm not able to wrap the request in a soap envelope, which I need to accept the credentials from the header.  Is there a way to accept the soap envelope in a RESTful service?

Comment: Since the client credential type of the webhttpbinding could be used for authentication. Wrapping the credentials in the request body(now it mainly consists of request data) is unwise. We could also use IDispatchMessageinsepctor and IclientMessageinspector interface to modify the HTTP request header and soap enveloper. This is a complex subject. we had better use webhttpbinding itself to authenticate the client.

Comment: I went over the documentation and messages are SOAP messages, so it looks like REST isn't an option.

Comment: for example, we could use the below Basic authentication.  <webHttpBinding>
        <binding name="mybinding">
          <security mode="TransportCredentialOnly">
            <transport clientCredentialType="Basic"></transport>
          </security>
        </binding>
      </webHttpBinding>