# Call WCF rest service with Javascript (JQuery) do not receive any response

Tags: javascript, rest, wcf

The **WCF** service **gets called** for sure (the debug kicks in).

**No response back** to javasript callbacks.

If i configure the call with **dataType:JSON the error callback is called**.

If i configure **dataType:JSONP no error occurs and no response is received** (no callback happens neither error or sucess or done).

```
$.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "jsonp",
        contentType: "application/json;charset-uf8",
        crossDomain: false,
        async: true,
        url: "http://myurl",

        done: function (results) {
            // Uhm, maybe I don't even need this?
            var parsed = JSON.parse(results);
            alert(parsed);
            return results;
        },

        success: function (data, text) {
            alert(text);
            alert(data);
        },

        error: function (request, status, error) {
            alert(request);
            alert(status);
            alert(error);
        }
    });
```

I'm running this on localhost. 
I have no clue at all, i don't even know how to get more in depth error details.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Directly sending an HTTP request to call the WCF service applies the Restful style service. Thereby we should ensure that WCF service is restful style whereas mostly WCF service based on the SOAP web service, and the invocation is completed by using client proxy class. 
From the description, I suggest you add a breakpoint on the JS statement then debug it in the browser. Besides, Success event is deprecated in Jquery, I suggest you use the Done event callback after the AJAX method.

```
$.ajax({
    method:"Get",
    url: "http://10.157.13.69:11000/Service1.svc/GetData?value=34",
    contentType:"application/json"
}).done(function(data){
    console.log(data);
})
```

I would like that you could post the code details on the server-side so that I try to make an example as much as possible.
At last, please refer to my previous demo on this topic, wish it is useful to you.
[How to fix "ERR_ABORTED 400 (Bad Request)" error with Jquery call to C# WCF service?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56873239/how-to-fix-err-aborted-400-bad-request-error-with-jquery-call-to-c-sharp-wcf/56879896#56879896)
Feel free to let me know if there is anything I can help with.

Comment: Hi, the WCF service itself gets called. I developed it and i'm running in local so i can access it easily. The breakpoint is on the webservice not on the js that calls it. No need code for the server side. The operation is configured as WEBGET. Non response still. done doesn't get called

Comment: The rest service is configured ok also because if i paste the url of the method to call directly in the browser i receive the proper data in json format. I can't get the same result via javascript. Any help appreciated

Comment: Pay attention to your content-type field. There is a typo in it.
contentType:" application/json; charset=utf-8"
if you don't explicitly specify the response data format to JSON on the server-side, please add this line in the Http request and ignore the datatype field.