# Does WCF Add Service Reference require something configured on the service to generate the app config?

Tags: wcf, visual-studio-2013, service-reference

We have an existing wcf service, and I created a new project. I want to use it. I hit add service reference, pop in the URL, press OK, and it adds it as a service reference but there is no config generated.

I also tried `svcutil.exe /language:cs /out:GeneratedProxy.cs /config:app.config [url]` but no config is generated, only the proxy cs.

I'm using VS 2013 / .NET 4.0

My question is, is this a sign that the SVC itself has some missing data that is required to build the contracts, or is the problem with adding the service reference?

For the record I have tried unchecking the reuse types option which some questions on here have reported as fixing the problem.

Bonus question, do you think if I can't get this working that manually adding some generic default bindings and endpoint code to the web config will work?

Comment: Can you share config of your WCF service?

Comment: I don't have access to the WCF service's config, only the WSDL, but my question is just asking if the client config is published by the service, i.e. the service tells the client what config to use, or, it's completely client side. Basically I want to know if it's a server issue or a client issue. Then I can debug accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

First, the reason that why the Adding service reference generates nothing is that the WCF service is rest style service. By default, the proxy-based invocation of rest style WCF services is complex.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/wcf-web-http-programming-model
Calling the WCF rest style service with the client proxy is uncommon. Generally, we construct an Http request by using an HTTP client library to call the service, such as HttpClient, WebClient.
[How to fix "ERR_ABORTED 400 (Bad Request)" error with Jquery call to C# WCF service?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56873239/how-to-fix-err-aborted-400-bad-request-error-with-jquery-call-to-c-sharp-wcf/56879896#56879896)
Besides, calling the WCF rest style service with the client proxy is feasible. Please refer to my previous link.
[WCF: There was no endpoint listening at, that could accept the message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54018130/wcf-there-was-no-endpoint-listening-at-that-could-accept-the-message/54068160#54068160)
Feel free to let me know if there is anything I can help with.